# How to access a variable from one function into another function in a different controller in the same project

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a controller where I have public function as shown below

```
class Add_project extends MY_Controller
{

 public function add_quotation_maker()
  {
    $this->data['AutomationFullnFinal'] = $this->data['AutomationDiningAndLivingArea'] + $this->data['AutomationLivingArea'] + $this->data['AutomationDiningArea'] + $this->data['AutomationKitchen'] + $this->data['AutomationEntireHome'];
}
}
```

Now, I have another controller and in which I have another function as shown below

```
class Make_pdf extends Add_project
{
public function index()
    {
      }
}
```

No, I want to use $this->data['AutomationFullnFinal'] from the Add_project controller into the Make_pdf controller inside the public function index.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Why You want to use like this. A Controller should not communicate other controller in codeigniter.

Comment: Make custom library or particular core controller where will be code that is used by route controllers.

Comment: where does your data array come from ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this Help You with little tweak :

```
  class Add_project extends CI_Controller
  {
    public function add_quotation_maker()
    {
      $this->data['AutomationFullnFinal'] = $this->data['AutomationDiningAndLivingArea'] + $this->data['AutomationLivingArea'] + $this->data['AutomationDiningArea'] + $this->data['AutomationKitchen'] + $this->data['AutomationEntireHome'];
     }
     public function test()
     {
        echo "string";;
     }
  }
```

**In `Make_pdf` file just include the above file :**

```
   include_once (dirname(__FILE__) . "/Add_project.php");
   class Make_pdf extends Add_project {
       public function test2()
       {
         $this->test();
       }
   }
```

now you can access the methods of `Add_project` class:

Answer (score 0):

It will achieve by below steps:
1> extend required class in controller.
2> Call that function by extended controller's object.

Comment: Can you be more precise in your answer? Why should a controller be extended?

Answer (score 0):

It would appear from the use of `$this->data` that the `Add_project` class has declared the property `$data`. If the visibility of `$data` is declared as `public` or `protected` it be usable in `Make_pdf` and accessed the same way e.g. `$this->data['whatever']`.

The declaration might look something like

```
class Add_project extends CI_Controller
{
   public $data;

   public function add_quotation_maker()

...
```